# where did the uhttpd file go for my wifi pineapple?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kali-linux

So, I decided to try out this wifi pineapple that's been sitting at my desk for a while. The wireless hacking book I have tells me to stop the web server to "free up resources for our survey." It is using the pineapple to try using airodump-ng as a tool on kali linux. I typed in the command it told me:

```
/etc/init.d/uhttpd stop
```

Yes, I'm sure I typed that in right. It gives me this:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/uhttpd no such file or directory
```

What is the reason why I am not getting this file. I check the init.d directory and the process does not exist as a file when I list the contents of the directory? Would having Kali on dual boot work rather than a VM solve any of these problems?

Comment: I do not have uhttpd either on my Kali. But I do have apache2, and this stops the Web server:  `systemctl stop apache2`, or `service apache2 stop`.

Comment: That won't work because I can't install tmux, gpsd, and gpsd clients

Comment: I think. Let me try to do it anyways.